# How to save json in LocalStorage using Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this line of code `JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem("search",data))` when i tried to console the `data` it works fine, i just want to save the result to the localstorage as JSON, this is the current result.

[image]

and I have this error

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

result of console.log()

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(data);` Looks like your `data` is not a valid JSON string

Comment: @kiranvj wait, Ill post the picture

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("search", JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is completely backwards.

You need to stringify the data **to** JSON not parse it **from** JSON and you need to do so on the value you pass **to** `setItem` not the value you get back **from** `setItem` (which is always `undefined`, hence the error).

```
localStorage.setItem("search",JSON.stringify(data))
```

That said, since you said you were using React, I would advise against manipulating localStorage directly. The [`useLocalStorage` hook](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) makes life much easier.

> ```
> import { useState } from "react";
>
> // Usage
> function App() {
>   // Similar to useState but first arg is key to the value in local storage.
>   const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage("name", "Bob");
>
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <input
>         type="text"
>         placeholder="Enter your name"
>         value={name}
>         onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
>       />
>     </div>
>   );
> }
>
> // Hook
> function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
>   // State to store our value
>   // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
>   const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
>     try {
>       // Get from local storage by key
>       const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
>       // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
>       return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
>     } catch (error) {
>       // If error also return initialValue
>       console.log(error);
>       return initialValue;
>     }
>   });
>
>   // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
>   // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
>   const setValue = (value) => {
>     try {
>       // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
>       const valueToStore =
>         value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
>       // Save state
>       setStoredValue(valueToStore);
>       // Save to local storage
>       window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
>     } catch (error) {
>       // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
>       console.log(error);
>     }
>   };
>
>   return [storedValue, setValue];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Quentin's answer is right, but you can also create a utility to manage data in local storage.

```
export const saveToLocal = (key, data) => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
};

export const getFromLocal = (key) => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return JSON.parse(data);
};

export const removeFromLocal = (key) => {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
};
```

Comment: Writing the utility as a hook is a better bet when working with React.

Comment: @Quentin right, but as I learned from my experience that keeping things simple as you can be better, writing a hook for it doesn't help you with performance or readability but increases the code which is useless I think

Comment: All the complexity in that hook will probably still be needed, it just won't be as organised as well.

Comment: Your code, for example, is missing the check to make sure that the key exists before trying to parse it as JSON. So `getFromLocal` can throw an exception really easily.

Comment: @Quentin error handling can be added easily according to the use case or requirement, it's not a big deal I think

Comment: please check I didn't claim that your answer is wrong, I'm just saying the hook you wrote is not needed, what if I have some class components in my project?